# Get Budo to save the generated output bundle

Tags: browserify, budo

I'm using [Budo](https://github.com/mattdesl/budo#docs) to develop a website using Browserify and Babelify like this:

```
budo src/index.js:static/bundle.js --live -- -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ]
```

That works great, except the generated `static/bundle.js` isn't actually saved to disk - it's just accessible in the browser. If I remove the path argument:

```
budo --live -- -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ]
```

Then it just serves a local file in `static/bundle.js` but doesn't regenerate it.

How do I get it to actually generate and save the file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've moved onto other things, but why would you want to save it to disk anyway?

But take a look at this build file I created if you really need to:
[build.js](https://github.com/peterbarraud/rapo-browserify-budo/blob/master/scripts/build.js)

Comment: Actually I still use Budo a lot. I need to save it to disk in order to publish to Github Pages. In practice I end up simply using `wget` to fetch and save it.

Comment: Btw I don't quite understand where your `build.js` fits. Seems to be using something called rimraf? Is this a standalone script or part of some framework?

Comment: "I still use Budo a lot" - Super great!!!. Regarding the build.js, I've put a whole lot of other stuff because I'm doing some css output also. If you take a look at lines 19-23. The main.js file is the starting point for my app - has all the initial includes (require or import statement). So I use browserify to pull all the includes together and then I use another module (uglifyify) to uglify my output js to build/bundle.js.

Comment: I've tried to describe how I've set up this template browserify+budo project that this build file is part of: https://github.com/peterbarraud/rapo-browserify-budo